# Does Hibernate support Amazon RDS and S3?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, amazon-web-services

After checking [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) and discovering that Hibernate support relational databases (Like MySQL) I would like to know if it support Amazon RDS. I am assuming that it does because of the ORM thing, but since I am very newbie I decided to come here and ask to the people who know.

Assuming that Hibernate can read from my MySQL database, I would also like to know if there is a way for it to actually support key-value database, like Amazon S3. I searched but I simply couldn't find anything else.

Finally, can someone let me know the level of support that Hibernate has for MySQL joins? I would like to know if it supports them and how much of it is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if there is a way for it to actually support key-value database, like
>   Amazon S3

There's a separate project for this, called [Hibernate OGM](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/ogm.html). It aims to support JPA for NoSQL databases. Check it out.

> can someone let me know the level of support that Hibernate has for
>   MySQL joins? I would like to know if it supports them and how much of
>   it is supported

Joins are definitely supported through Criteria API, and definitely in HQL. You need to be more specific on what you really want to achieve in order to get a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks, I know about the existence of OGM, but you are correct, I should be more specific. I will create a new post with more detailed information about my problem. Thank you for your time! karma++!